# Importing data (Custom Data Sources and API)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I'm trying import costs with Custom Data Source feature. Always, when I call dailyUploads.import, I get error "Upload request url should start with https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/..." (code 400). Import data from analytics page is impossible, only API is allowed. I'm using google web console and Ruby API client and I can't import data. Any suggestions?

Screenshot from Google API Console: https://01456665495003716876.googlegroups.com/attach/4ce463bf69ca18eb/Google%20Developers%20Console.png?part=4&view=1&vt=ANaJVrEczYmf4aVCSx3pyK9CsPtTuGTzAFB9G5tP3gUpVv4gxShimmj1s-80K7msHHbptiu69bCySj_4hiS9cvMjob7gwyw2sgHBZdF6j7IFnFzDErSBrtM

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can **actually** upload data via the API Explorer. You can use the code from [Farina](https://github.com/CharlesFarina/Google-Analytics-Cost-Data-Upload--Python-) (http://www.e-nor.com/) written in Python to have things done however.

Answer (score 0):

The [dailyUpload](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/dailyUploads/upload) reference docs also provide an example in both Java and Python. But you might consider [migrating](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/cost-data-migration) to the [uploads](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport) resource which allows you to upload directly through the Google Analytics web interface.